# Meaning of "Over the balance of something" in "You'll be subjected to hearing new information over the balance of the semester."

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

Example:

> I would like to close with just a few remarks on the question, "Why study
>   classical mythology? Why study the marginally incoherent tales of some people
>   who have been dead going on three thousand years, now. What does this have to
>   do with me?" I have a lot of reason. You'll be subjected to them over **the balance
>   of the semester**. But the image I keep coming back to: If you can imagine. You've
>   all applied to Southwest Missouri State University. You've all gotten paperwork
>   from Southwest Missouri State University. You can all probably, by now, close
>   your eyes and see the official logo of Southwest Missouri State University, which
>   is the portico—the front porch if you will—of Carrington Hall.

What exactly does that mean? I looked up the word *balance* in the dictionary, but couldn't find the meaning that would fit the semantics exactly.

Comment: [***balance***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/balance) - "12) (US) whatever is left over; remainder"

Comment: Doesn't sound like it at all. The course has not even started yet. It's only the introduction part where the lecturer says that.

Comment: Did the semester already start?

Comment: @CookieMonster: If one is even in a lecture, the course has started enough for "balance" to take on that meaning. 0.01% is still "partially finished".

Comment: A nice expression! I've never noticed it before.

Comment: It seems like the closing remarks from the first lecture for a course. So in the remaining lectures the reasons will be revealed. // It really seems that in the sentence "I have a lot of reason" that reason should be plural. So "I have a lot of reasons." //

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase "(over) the balance of [time period]" is used quite widely in journalism, judging by a Google News search.

> One important factor to watch for precious metals is the Federal Reserve **over the balance of the year**. (over the remaining portion of the year)

Interestingly, it is also used without **over**:

> The dollar's strength will have an impact on our performance **for the balance of the year** and could impact 2016 as well. (for the rest of the year)

It's not only in financial and business news that the expression is found. Here's a sports news report:

> After seeing limited action while playing in 21 games his first two seasons, he was third on the team in rushing in 2013. Off to a strong start in 2014, he suffered an injury that sidelined him and allowed him to sit out **the balance of the year** as a redshirt and gain an added season of eligibility. ([source](http://www.herald-citizen.com/sports/item/11110-three-named-to-cosida-all-district-team))

Here's a weather forecast:

> “The predictions for **the balance of the month** do not look good,” he said. “I can tell you that we’re not seeing any appreciable rainfall for **the balance of the month** at this point in time.” ([source](http://antiguaobserver.com/showers-welcomed-but-drought-outlook-still-grim/))